# fontawesome 5 some icons are not rendering

Tags: html, font-awesome

Issue with font awesome version 5. Some icons are not getting rendered. Instead shows animation with question mark and exclamation. If I use version 4 and css it gets rendered. Anyone have this issue ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="body">

<i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i>
<i class="fas fa-google-plus-square"></i>
<i class="fas fa-check-square"></i>

</body>

</html>
```

Here the google-plus-square icon is not rendering. This is how it appears in the browser
[image]

Comment: Comment from Manish below lead to me further research. There are a number of prefix changes. You will be able to see it all here. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Because you are calling wrong class

**This Is Wrong**
<i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i>
<i class="fas fa-google-plus-square"></i>

**For Font Awesome 5 Instead of That USe THis**
<i class="fab fa-google-plus-square"></i>
```

**Search Icon From Here**
https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Use this link instead of script

Answer (score 0):

Another reason your font-awesome icons are not rendering could be that you are trying to use a Pro icon when you have the `fontawesome-free` package.

For example, in Font Awesome 6, to use `<i class="fa-solid fa-code"></i>`, `fontawesome-pro` package is required.